# In CakePHP, override AppController's redirect() to respond with a url via json during ajax requests

Tags: php, rest, cakephp, authentication

My controller methods serve dual purpose: To both handle traditional browser requests AND to interact via REST clients using mapped resources.

Case: This is convenient because I can keep all of my validation centralized in Cake models and still have nice ajax forms that I can validate by extracting Model::validationErrors and adding them to the json response.  Where I don't care if a form is ajax, I can simply NOT apply my client-side javascript and the form and server communicate normally.

Problem: Many controller actions rely on Controller::redirect().  By overriding redirect(), trying beforeRedirect(), etc, **I can find NO reliable way to convert the redirect into a JSON response during an ajax request that would indicate something like 'redirectUrl' => 'foo' so that my client (in the case of browser ajax) can forward the user to a new url using javascript location redirect.**

I thought I had it working but realized that unauthorized users had access to run protected resources despite not seeing their output.

Comment: I don't have a high enough reputation to post my own answer, sorry.

Comment: See line 1002 of the component in the "cake rest plugin" on github.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json array with two keys like

```
$json['status'] => 'success',
$json['url'] => 'router::url ("/",array("controller" => "yourcontroller",
                  "action" => "youraction"))';
// url where you want redirect after some processing

return json_encode($json);
```

**//In your Script from you was send ajax request:**

```
if(json['status'] == 'success'){
   window.location.href = json['url'];
}
```